# Low FPS when using nomodeset

Tags: 14.04, nomodeset

I have an HP Pavilion tx2560es. I can only get ubuntu 14.04 to boot with the nomodeset option, but that gives me very slow animations (apps opening/closing, lag in the text editors, etc). If I boot it without nomodeset it works fine for a while until the screen just freezes and glitches and the only way out is a forceful shutdown. Any help?

Comment: To be able to help you, we need some information about your video chipset. I can't find your exact model, but the 2670 tells me you may have a Radeon HD 3200 in there. I suspect you are running llvmpipe (software OpenGL) instead of radeon (or whatever). 
Post info from 'sudo lspci -vv' or 'sudo lshw'. Thanks!